# Redirect from a TAB to a Website

Tags: facebook, redirect, tabs, facebook-page, facebook-fbml

My developement team is creating diferent Tabs for one of our Facebook Brand Pages.

These tabs are intended to redirect the user to specific sections in the company's website.

I suggested that instead of automatically redirect the user we should add a message like:

"You are being redirected to our company website"

Im thinking about user experience and based on that i suggested this previous step, but the head of the developer unit says theres no reason to do that.

I would like to hear your opinions on this matter, ¿should we inform the user that he is being redirected or should we redirect him automatically?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As a personal preference, I would prefer to be informed that I'm being redirected. Unless you state this somewhere else on the page where i can see it. It isn't needed, but it is sometimes nice.

Answer (score 0):

So is the idea that when a user clicks on one of the tabs that they'll be redirected right then or there, or that something will show up in the tab from your website (like in an iframe)?

I believe that redirecting the user after they click a tab is a bad idea. I hope these tabs will be FBML tabs with some text and links to direct the user where you want them to go, instead of redirecting the whole window away from Facebook on tab click.